# Как найти нужный код в Joomla?

Tags: css3, html5, joomla, php7, joomla3

***[Сайт](https://easy-moving.ca)***

*[Ссылка на валидатор](https://html5.validator.nu/?doc=https%3A%2F%2Feasy-moving.ca)*

### Нашел ошибки на сайте.

> Error: Element style not allowed as child of element div in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)

From line 87, column 1; to line 87, column 23

wrapper">↩#as-me

Вся проблема в том что этот код загружается вообще и кэша. А откуда берется оригинал Я не могу найти. Подскажите пожалуйста, кто встречался с подобным как найти нужный код чтобы исправить. Уже неделю ищу понять не могу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При просмотре кода в броузере.
Я обратил внимание на то как формируется код там.
Увидел что это стиль относиться к модулю Mod_as_Menu ну а дальше не составило труда найти и справить нужный css